# Oracle insert optimization using JDBC Driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am inserting 1 million records in an empty oracle table. In order to improve insert performance I have tried following optimizations:

- giving /*+ APPEND */ hint in insert query
- disabling index
  before insert and then re-enabling it once insertion is done
- enabling nologging on the table.

However, I am not able to see any improvement in the insert performance. I am not able to figure out why.

Note that I am using `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate#batchUpdate` for inserting records and I am inserting records in the batch of 20000.

Comment: what is your select statament ? directly from one table?

Comment: No, I am reading data from kafka and inserting in an Oracle table.

Comment: one 2 one ? so you can insert your data parallel

Comment: Yes, I can't see any problem in inserting in parallel.

Comment: Are there any `trigger`s in the target table? And are you sure that the slowness is caused by the DB? Do you read all the data from Kafka, after which you start inserting to the DB, or do you read while you're adding to the batch? How long does insering the 1M rows take currently? If you want good suggestions, please share some relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Earliar Oracle has published Document regarding Performance tuning for JDBC: [Oracle JDBC Memory Management](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/memory.pdf)

Here are the few tips

1. Optimise the batch size ,depending on your oracle configuration.
2. Cache the preparedstatement and use the same statement for all batches (Need cleanup) or Use statement pooling (Oracle JDBC Driver Supports it. See the above document).
3. Oracle has few Performance extensions defined: [Performance Extensions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28752). Instead of `addBatch` use `sendBatch` for improving batch performance.See Example 23-1 in above document.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Oracle style batching using `setExecuteBatch` and `sendBatch` was desupported in 12.